# Choosing files from only one row in a table angular

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, typescript, angular5

I have a table in which a single column consists of the option of choosing files. I have done that but my problem is that when I choose files in a particular row the files get choose in all the rows. Even if I delete it gets deleted in all rows. I want it to be selected or deleted in only one row.

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4vnwed?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: I have a solution, but it requires you to modify the `listes` data model to include an array for files.

Comment: Pls modify whatever u want as per ur wish.(Keeping the functionality same) @Randy

Comment: Hey thanks for the help but I already got the answer from another user. But if your free please write it would be interesting to see your methodology too

Comment: You can always change the accepted answer if you think my solution, (_which relates the files with the data row_), is a better answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some modification that will maintain the list of files with the actual record (row).

First modify the `listes` data model:

```
{
      name: "A",
      qty: 6,
      value: 10,
      files: [] // added files array here
    },
```

Next, modify the `getFileDetails`  code. You need the index and the target. Then, find the list by index and push the target.files onto that listes object (row):

```
  getFileDetails (index, e) {
    //console.log (e.target.files);
    for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
      this.listes[index].files.push(e.target.files[i]);
    }
    console.log(this.myFiles)
  }
```

Change the `delete` method to delete the selected file from the selected index. In this case we need two indexes, one for the list and one for the files. These are created inside the HTML (below):

```
  deleteRow(listIndex: number, fileIndex: number) {
    this.listes[listIndex].files.splice(fileIndex,1);
  }
```

Finally the changes necessary to the html are minimal, but relate to the indexes I mentioned above:

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let list of listes; index as listIndex">
                        <td>{{listIndex+1}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.qty}}</td>
                        <td>{{list.value}}</td>
                        <div style="overflow: auto;">
                            <td>
                                <div>
                                    <ng-container>
                                        <input type="file"  multiple
            (change)="getFileDetails(listIndex, $event)">
                                    </ng-container>
                                </div>
                                <div *ngFor="let file of list.files; index as fileIndex">
                                    <div>* {{file.name}}</div>
                                    <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(listIndex, fileIndex)" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
                                </div>
                            </td>
                        </div>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
```

OP asked about clearing the file input after files are deleted. The following change accomplishes that:

```
    <input #fileInput type="file" multiple (change)="getFileDetails(listIndex, $event)">
    </ng-container>
    </div>
    <div *ngFor="let file of list.files; index as fileIndex">
      <div>* {{file.name}}</div>
      <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(listIndex, fileIndex); fileInput.value = ''" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
```

The working blitz can be found here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-gepzrz?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Thank u so much. But the stackblitz is not working ?

Comment: I am saying that its not loading

Comment: @angular Please check now. Sorry about the bad link. It will work now.

Comment: I have a doubt.In this code where have you written choose files. I mean I took the code sample from google. I still didnt figure out how choose files button name came because I havent named any button choose files?

Comment: Even after deleting a file why the name of file still exists in the side to the button? @Randy

Comment: The file name remains behind because you've decided not to use Angular's form features. So, the input element never gets set back to it's initial state. Also, the [Choose files] label and the button are the default UI for an input that has a `type` attribute of `files`.

Comment: Those points, by the way, are completely unrelated to the question. If you want those answered, you should ask a different question.

Comment: My answer is still the best answer, because it links the files to the related data! :-)

Comment: Okay thanks I have accepted urs. So is there anyway to remove to remove that file name after delete?

Comment: I've fixed the blitz and updated the answer to reset the input.

Comment: This code is not working in my Vs Code . Is there any reason?  When I choose files the current file name alone comes by side. If I choose another it replaces the existing one instead of adding up. Pleas tell if u have any idea?

Comment: In console the error is cannot read push method of undefined

Comment: This code works fine in StackBlitz - which is literally VS Code on the web. Unfortunately, I have no way of knowing what is on your computer. This is why many suggest that cut-n-paste programming doesn't work. I recommend you spend more time learning about Angular and how to make it work for you rather than cutting and pasting bits and pieces of code from Google searches (as you've stated you've done here).

Comment: Hey I have found out the problem for that. I have to initialize in vs code.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65261110/calculate-checkbox-enabled-rows-and-display-in-another-table-angular   can u please check this question?

Comment: @angular - just saw this - but see you got your answer.

Comment: Its fine. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

When file in any row is selected, you have following same code in each row:

```
<div *ngFor="let file of myFiles; let i=index">
  <div>* {{file.name}}</div>
  <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
</div>
```

which prints all files in each row. Store files per some row identifier (for example `name`).

So change

```
myFiles: any[] = [];
```

to

```
myFiles: Record<string, File[]> = {};
```

`getFileDetails()` function should receive `name` key:

```
getFileDetails (e, name) {
  //console.log (e.target.files);
  for (var i = 0; i < e.target.files.length; i++) { 
    this.myFiles[name] = this.myFiles[name] || [];
    this.myFiles[name].push(e.target.files[i]);
  }
  console.log(this.myFiles)
}
```

`uploadFiles()`:

```
uploadFiles() {
  const frmData = new FormData();

  Object.values(this.myFiles).flat().forEach(file => frmData.append("fileUpload", file));
}
```

`deleteRow()` function should receive `name` key:

```
deleteRow(index: number, name: string) {
  this.myFiles[name].splice(index,1);
  // reset file input element
  (document.querySelector(`#file_${name}`) as HTMLInputElement).files = undefined;
}
```

Relevant TD HTML:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <ng-container>
      <input type="file" id="file" multiple
        (change)="getFileDetails($event, list.name)">
    </ng-container>
  </div>

  <div *ngFor="let file of myFiles[list.name]; let i=index">
    <div>* {{file.name}}</div>
    <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(i, list.name)" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
  </div>
</td>
```

Please note that `Object.values(this.myFiles).flat()` may not yet be supported in STACKBLITZ, but [should work](https://caniuse.com/?search=flat) in any modern browser.

You can use following instead:

```
Object.values(this.myFiles).reduce((res, curr) => [
  ...res,
  ...curr
], []).forEach(file => frmData.append("fileUpload", file));
```

Working [STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vh6os5?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thank u so so muchhhh @Andriy

Comment: I have a doubt.In this code where have you written choose files. I mean I took the code sample from google. I still didnt figure out how choose files button name came because I havent named any button choose files?

Comment: Even after deleting a file why the name of file still exists in the side to the button?

Comment: good point, I did not reset HTML element, I updated my STACKBLITZ

Comment: Its still not working pls check

Answer (score 0):

@angular remove `ngFor` for files in your table loop like below. Because it loop same files again and again.

```
<div>* {{myFiles[i].name}}</div>
<button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
```

instead of this

```
<div *ngFor="let file of myFiles; let i=index">
  <div>* {{myFiles[i].name}}</div>
  <button type="button" (click)="deleteRow(i)" class="btn btn-primary">X</button>
</div>
```

Then you declared file object contain of index, file, isUpload like below

```
myfiles: {index: string, file: any, isUpload: boolean}[] = [];
```

Please check with stackblitz reference url.

Reference: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-jbgfgn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: The OP's blitz specifically allows for multiple files to be selected. Without the loop, there is no way to accommodate multiple selection.

Comment: Thanks for the try. But say for example if I choose files in first row and then I choose in 4 th row the file also gets added to 2nd row and another bug in this code is the delete button is not working for other rows  @Arun