# Calculate checkbox enabled rows and display in another table angular

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, angular, typescript

I have a two tables totally **Table1** and **table2**. **Table1** is filled with data from a service. In **Table1** I have columns such as **Qty**,**Price** and **Checkbox**. In the checkbox columns I have checkboxes as values. The qty and price have number as values
In **table2** I have columns named **Qty** and **Price**

Pics of table 1 and 2

[image: TABLE1]

[image: TABLE2]

Now say if I click the checkbox in row 1,2,4 in **table1**. So if you take the **Qty** column in **table1** all the **Qty** values in row 1,2,4 should be added and be shown in **qty** column in **table2** as a single value. Same goes for **price** column. (Example 6,4,2 are the values of **qty** column in row 1,2,4 so add(6+4+2) and show total in first row of **qty** column in table2

[image: ROW1,2,4CHECKED]

I am trying to do this for two days couldn't find a solution.I know its a very difficult one.
Please help me if u can.

**STACKBLITZ**:  https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-coydaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Make a runnable snippet

Comment: I have attached a stackblitz already.https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-coydaf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  @jqueryHtmlCSS

Comment: Show your HTML.

Comment: I have shown my html in the stackblitz.2 tables tootally.In the second table only columns will be there

Comment: Hi you need to do this using jquery/js  ?

Comment: js is fine but please dont use pure js.I am actually doing this in typecript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a variable at component level which will hold the total count.

```
totalCount: any;
```

Initialize it in `ngOnInit` event.

```
this.totalCount = {qty:0,value:0};
```

on Checkbox `onChange` event invoke below function which will add/substract based on checked status.

```
getTotal(event,item) {
    if (event.target.checked) {
      this.totalCount.qty =  this.totalCount.qty + item.qty;
      this.totalCount.value =  this.totalCount.value + item.value;
    } else {
      this.totalCount.qty =  this.totalCount.qty - item.qty;
      this.totalCount.value =  this.totalCount.value - item.value;
    }
}
```

Display the value like this.

```
<tr *ngIf="!(totalCount.qty == 0 || totalCount.value == 0)">
    <td>1</td>
    <td>{{totalCount.qty}}</td>
    <td>{{totalCount.value}}</td>
</tr>
```

Working StackBlitz:-

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-349pwn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: Hey thanks for that I am trying to keep a button below. So that the change in the second table shows only after button click.When I tried I couldnt access the list and the event value like u did before using onchange. I have also made a onclick in button and in that I have called the getTotal() you have done by using this,getTotal() inside the button onclick and that too didnt work. any ideas?

Comment: It will not work, try to understand the logic. onChange is for each item, how can it will work on button click.

Comment: If you want to do it on a button click you need to change the logic on getTotal function

Comment: If I use a button click how will I be accessing the $event and list values if I am gonna keep that button outside the table?

Comment: You cant access event in that case.

Comment: can we do it like "Only activate the ngif in table two after button click"?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/225853/discussion-between-vimal-patel-and-angular).